# Convert byte Address to Hex

Tags: go-ethereum, addresses, golang

Using Geth I am reading from a smart contract and a list of addresses is retrieved when outputting to the terminal. These addresses are in byte array format:

```
fmt.printLn("address", address)
output = address  [16 22 32 12 22 0 0 0 0 0 16 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3]
```

when I try to convert back to hex I keep coming against the following:

```
cannot use address (type common.Address) as type string in argument to bytes.NewBufferString
```

So far, I have tried various different ways to make the conversion but with no luck: `string(address[:] etc etc..`.

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: Have you tried `string(address.GetBytes())`?

Comment: its throws ```address.GetBytes undefined (type common.Address has no field or method GetBytes)```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to convert from binary to hex, and back, use the package [encoding/hex](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/)

Hex ==> string:

```
str := hex.EncodeToString(**your slice of bytes**)
```

Hex <== string:

```
b, err := hex.DecodeString(**your string**)
```

Comment: address.Sum undefined (type common.Address has no field or method Sum)

Comment: oh sorry about that, the input is your slice of bytes

Comment: Sweet! that did the trick

Comment: that's if you want lower case address, if you want a checksumed just do `str:=address_var.Hex()`

Comment: `hexutil.Decode` also works.

Answer (score 2):

go-ethereum also provides a [`hexutil`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/common/hexutil) package.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
)

func main() {
    addrBytes := []byte{20, 123, 142, 185, 127, 210, 71, 208, 108, 64, 6, 210, 105, 201, 12, 25, 8, 251, 93, 84}
    fmt.Println(hexutil.Encode(addrBytes)) // 0x147B8eb97fD247D06C4006D269c90C1908Fb5D54

    addrHex, _ := hexutil.Decode("0x147B8eb97fD247D06C4006D269c90C1908Fb5D54")
    fmt.Println(addrHex) // [20 123 142 185 127 210 71 208 108 64 6 210 105 201 12 25 8 251 93 84]
}
```